# JSon returning Integer values into array

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I have successfully realized the interaction with json and returning successfully all the required entities. But i have one field that will be returned as an integer. I want to do the simplest thing and access an element of the array , which is an integer , and compare it with another integer. No matter what i do it doesn't work out : this is my code so far :

```
NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyURL"];
NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL2]];

NSString *strResult2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json2 = [strResult2 JSONValue];

userExists = [json2 valueForKeyPath:@"userId"];
```

Where userExists is an array, and the values stored in it are NOT strings , they are Int.
Any help?!

Comment: It would help if you show the value of `strResult2` (the JSON response) and `json2`.

Comment: Most JSON frameworks box numbers in `NSNumber` objects, so `[theObject integerValue]` will get you the `NSInteger` for it (or of course you could compare the numbers via `compare:`)

Comment: @MartinR the value of strResult2 is : {"ExtensionData":{},"token":null,"userId":0}"

Comment: Then @Alladinian has got the solution, so he might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Alladinian i tried this :  NSInteger *exists = [[userExists objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] ; but it didn't work…if there anything more specific i would highly appreciate it

Comment: @MartinR could you please comment me the answer and if aAlladinian answers, i would mark him as the answer.. plz and thank you

Comment: userExists is an array as you mention, but userId is not an array but an Integer.

Comment: @Yarneo that's true, the array is userExists , but userId is an integer that i load inside the array

Comment: Then why is there an '=' sign rather than, [userExists addObject:[json2 valueForKeyPath:@"userId"]]

Comment: @Yarneo i am new with json actually , could you please post a snippet so i could understand more, thank you

Comment: @EliasRahme What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Also, where is the comparison taking place in your code?

Comment: @Alladinian the array userExists has only one entry which is userID, this userId in an integer returned from Json, i just want to compare this entry to the number " 0 " . Am i missing anything?

Comment: Use objectForKey, not valueForKeyPath. valueForKeyPath will lead to some subtle bugs; read it's documentation for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyURL"];
NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL2]];

NSString *strResult2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json2 = [strResult2 JSONValue];
```

Now if you want to add the integer to the array (has to be NSMutableArray of course) userExists, you do it like so:

```
[userExists addObject:[[json2 objectForKey:@"userId"] integerValue]]
```

If your intention was to compare the returned integer with an integer in the array at index i then you do it like so:

```
if([userExists objectAtIndex:i] == [[json2 objectForKey:@"userId"] integerValue]) {
....
}
```

Comment: if i try this code i will get an error and a warning on : [userExists addObject:[[json2 objectForKey:@"userId"] integerValue]]
the error is  : Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' aka('int') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: what could be causing this problem ? @Yarneo

Comment: Is userExists built from NSNumbers or from NSIntegers?
What does userExists contain already

Comment: Try: [userExists addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[json2 objectForKey:@"userId"] integerValue]]]

Comment: userExist is a NSMutableArray that i only called like this :   userExists = [json2 valueForKeyPath:@"userId"]; in order to have the element userId in it, i would like to access it and compare it with the number "0". am i missing anything…please bare with me i am new in json

Comment: Did you initialise it? userExist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]

Comment: Then I don't see why it shouldn't work. Try using the NSNumber example I gave 3 comments above.

Comment: I did !!! thank you so much @Yarneo, in addition to ur answer i added the following line and everything is ok :
    [userExists addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[json2 objectForKey:@"userId"] integerValue]]];
    NSNumber *UserIsIT =[userExists objectAtIndex:0];
    
    
    if([UserIsIT intValue] == 0){
    
        NSLog(@"User does not Exist!");
    
    }

Comment: @EliasRahme No need to convert back & forth. `[userExists addObject:[json2 objectForKey:@"userId"]]` would be fine.

Comment: Im glad I could be of help !